# Config file for logging in dart

Tags: dart, logging

I need to do logging to dart. I found the "logging" library, but it does not provide for loading settings through a config file, as is the case with log4j and others. Tell me please

I found Dart-Log-4-Part-2 but it's not very good to use according to the reviews

Comment: Can you please list all of the requirements you expect from a logger?

Comment: level, target, name

Comment: I'm not familiar with log4j, can you be more precise in the queestion?